# How to stop the thread in android activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing an android application which works on threads How to stop or destroy the thread in android while i was passing to the next activity can any one tell me please i am new to this

Comment: Hahaha... so funny i know that but i need a perfect answer dude that's why i am  posting here if you know the answer please tell me @MD

Comment: You definitely get perfect answer from _Google_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onStop() method, call interrupt as follows:

```
yourThreadObject.interrupt()
```

and in the run() method of the thread, have a condition that checks for Thread's interrupt status. Depending on your implementation, you might want to enclose this check within a while loop as,

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        //do something
        ...
    }
}
```

or you might check at certain points in the run() method as,

```
public void run() {
    //do something
    ...

    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        return;
    }

    //do something
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and finish() after you call next activity. 
For eg.,

```
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: OP is talking about Thread not Activity..